# Hamburger Icon with MaterialDrawer

Tags: android, drawer, materialdrawer

I'm trying to add to my toolbar the hamburger icon using the MaterialDrawer library. And I could put the icon the icon into the toolbar with this code

```
        // Handle Toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);   
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_action_name);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Before that I create the drawer

```
Drawer result = new DrawerBuilder()
 ...
 .build();
```

Finally, I use the instructions of the library to add the hamburger icon

```
result.getActionBarDrawerToggle().setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
```

And when I execute the code, it give me the follow error in the las line and dont run the application

*Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sergi.drawerexample/com.example.sergi.drawerexample.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference*

Someone could help me, I dont know what its happend

Thanks

Comment: typical nullpointer exception. Check the stacktrace to see which object is null and make sure you initialize it first.

Comment: also read this https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/issues/650

Answer (score 0):

As [zunjae](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50407606/hamburger-icon-with-materialdrawer/50423766#comment87830700_50407606) correctly has pointed out you must check why that object is null and try to initialize it before calling their methods. [zunjae](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50407606/hamburger-icon-with-materialdrawer/50423766#comment87830729_50407606) have sent you to an issue where you can find the solution:

```
result = new DrawerBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withToolbar(toolbar)
            .build();

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
result.getActionBarDrawerToggle().setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
```

I hope this helps you.